# A $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$ s.t. $\int f \,d\mu=\int g \,d\mu \implies f=g$ pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is the final part of a problem on an old Analysis preliminary exam at my institution. We are given that $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb R,\mu)$ and $f\leq g$.

For earlier parts of the problem, I've already showed that when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, we have that $$\int_{\mathbb R} f\ d\mu=\int_{\mathbb R} g\ d\mu\implies f=g \quad\mathrm{a.e.}$$ I've also already showed that if we add the assumption that $f,g$ are continuous, then we can strengthen the above to $f=g$ (everywhere).

The final part of the problem wants a Borel measure as described in the title. I have a hard time thinking of possibilities to consider. The Lebesgue measure and the counting measure are the only two $\sigma-$finite Borel measures on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$ that I can think of, and neither of them fits the bill. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Here is the exact text as it appeared on the preliminary exam.**

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. Let $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb R,\lambda)$ satisfy $f\leq g$.

Part (a): If $\int_\mathbb{R}f d\lambda=\int_\mathbb{R}g d\lambda$, show that $f=g$ almost everywhere.

[Part (b) is not relevant to my question.]

Part (c): Describe a $\sigma-$finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$ with respect to which the conclusion of part (a) is true for all points (instead of almost everywhere).

Comment: $\int f \, d\mu = \int g \, d\mu \implies f = g$ is vague; it seems that you want $f=g$ to mean pointwise equivalence, but for $f, g \in L^1(\mu)$, there's no such thing, as functions aren't defined pointwise, but as equivalence classes. So if $f = g$ means $f = g$ in $L^1(\mu)$, in the sense that $\int |f - g| = 0 \iff f = g$ a.e., then the Lebesgue measure still works.

Comment: @JonWarneke I have edited to add the exact text of the question as it appeared on the preliminary exam. Could you say what you think is the correct interpretation of the question, with regards to the vagueness you pointed out?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible (see the answer). Where did you find this prelim exam? For what school?

Comment: @JonWarneke This was the prelim exam in Analysis at Clemson two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is saying (in less precise terms) this:

let $f, g \colon \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be functions (so they're defined at all points $x \in \mathbb R$) such that $f \leq g$ (that is, $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$) and $f, g \in L^1(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

The question (c) is then: find a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(\mathbb R) = \infty$ and 
$$
\int f \, d\mu = \int g \, d\mu \implies f(x) = g(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R \tag{1}.
$$
We prove that no such $\mu$ exists by contradiction (filling in the details of the outline @ArunKumar gave).

So, suppose that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(\mathbb R)= \infty$ which satisfies $(1)$. Fix $(c_0, x_0) \in \mathbb R^2$, and define $f, g, h \colon \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= c_0, \\
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
c_0, & x \neq x_0 \\
c_0 + 1, & x = x_0
\end{cases} \\
h(x) &= (g-f)(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \neq x_0 \\
1, & x = x_0
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
These are all simple functions, so by the definition of the Lebesgue integral wrt $\mu$,
$$
\int(g-f) \, d\mu = \int h \, d\mu = 0 \cdot \mu\left( \mathbb R \backslash \{x_0\} \right) + 1 \cdot \mu(\{x_0\}) = \mu(\{x_0\})
$$
where we've used the fact that $\mu$ is a Borel measure. Since $f \neq g$ pointwise, the contrapositive of $(1)$ tells us that $\int f \, d\mu \neq \int g \, d\mu$, or
$$
0 \neq \int (g - f) \, d\mu = \int h \, d\mu = \mu(\{x_0\}),
$$
so $\{x_0\}$ has positive measure. Since $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ was arbitrary, we conclude that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ has positive measure:
$$
\mathbb R \supseteq A \neq \varnothing \iff \mu(A) > 0. \tag{2}
$$

Now suppose that $\mathbb R$ is $\sigma$-finite:
$$
\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n, \qquad \mu(A_n) < \infty.
$$
For each $n \in \mathbb N$ we can write
$$
A_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \underbrace{\left\{ x \in \mathbb R : \tfrac{1}{k} \leq \mu(\{x\} \cap A_n) \right\}}_{A_{n,k}}.
$$
To confirm this, note that
\begin{align*}
x \in A_n &\implies \{x\} \cap A_n \neq \varnothing \\
&\implies \mu(\{x\} \cap A_n ) > 0 &&\text{by $(2)$} \\
&\implies \mu(\{x\} \cap A_n) \geq \tfrac{1}{k} \quad \text{for some } k \in \mathbb N && \text{Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$} \\
&\implies x \in A_{n,k}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
x \in A_{n,k} \text{ for some } k \in\mathbb N &\implies \mu(\{x\} \cap A_n) > 0 \\
&\implies \{x\} \cap A_n \neq \varnothing \\
&\implies x \in A_n.
\end{align*}
We claim that $A_{n,k}$ is finite, which will give us our contradiction, since we've expressed the uncountable set $\mathbb R$ as a countable union of finite sets $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{n,k}$, which is countable. To see that $A_{n,k}$ is finite, suppose that $x_1, \dots, x_m$ are distinct points in $A_{n,k}$; then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{k} \leq \mu(\{x_i\} \cap A_n) &\implies \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \leq \sum_{i=1}^m \mu(\{x_i\} \cap A_n) = \mu\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^m \{x_i\} \cap A_n \right) \leq \mu(A_n) \\
&\implies m \leq k \mu(A_n) < \infty.
\end{align*}
(In particular, if we had chosen $m > k \mu(A_n)$, we'd get a contradiction.) Hence $A_{n,k}$ is finite, completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find such a measure. If you want $\int f=\int g\implies f=g$, then you cannot have measure zero subsets, as else you can have two functions which are equal everywhere except on a measure zero set. Then they will have the same integral. In particular singleton sets will have non-zero measure. But then such a measure cannot be $\sigma$-finite.

Edit: I removed the second solution as I did not notice that the functions are $L^1$. But my above argument still holds, such a measure cannot have measure zero sets, I can choose the functions as above with $f\leq g$.

Comment: They have the assumption $f \leq g$ and they also write $f=g$ a.e. (The title is bad.)

Comment: @Ian It was to be proven as part of the problem that $f=g$ a.e. Also, it is of course possible to have $f=g$ a.e. without having $f\leq g$, so these two assumptions seem to me to be neither redundant nor contradictory. Can you explain why the title is bad?

Comment: @arunkumar I have edited the question to include the exact text as it appeared on the preliminary exam. Could you say whether I have misinterpreted the question, or whether it is indeed not possible to find such a measure?

Comment: @Ian the OP has edited the question to make it explicit that the equality must be pointwise.